# Is this an hypoelliptic operator?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

$$Lu = -\Delta u + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^na_iu(x_i)$$

Is this an elliptic operator? According to definition, it doesn't seem to fit in.
Is this an [hypoelliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_operator#Elliptic_regularity_theorem) operator?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge elliptic an hypoelliptic operators are both differential operators, so in particular *local* operators. The one you wrote is not local, in that it depends on the value of the function in some points $x_i$ different from the (implicit) point $x$ at which you compute the value of the operator.

Comment: @Kore-N : thanks. Completely agree with you. Thanks for clearing the air. This not really a differential equation in true sense. This puts many things in right perspective.